# How to use types with module declaration locally?

Tags: typescript

I am working on a package that will be published in npm.
The package has a default exported js class. I want to provide typings for this class.
So what I've tried:

```
// src/index.ts
export default class SomeClass {
  test(data: string) {
    console.log(data)
  }
}

// types.d.ts
declare module 'some-module' {
  export default class SomeClass {
    test(data: string): void
  }
}
```

This approach works well if it is an npm module. When I import it like `import SomeClass from 'some-module'` it is imported with types.

But I can't use types from `types.d.ts` locally (in `src/index.ts`)

Is there a way to use types locally as well as in npm module?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
// src/index.ts
import SomeClassType from '../types'

export default class SomeClass implements SomeClassType {
  test(data: string) {
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```